# Converting a curved image to straightened image using OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

[This image perfectly shows the expected output.As you can see text in image is straightened.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQZP3.png)

I have written in python using openCV. It have rotated the image but not the text. I have used various methods . Please provide explanation with code as I am new to openCV.

```py
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    import math
    from scipy import ndimage
    img = cv2.imread(r'curved.jpg');
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1] 
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    points=[]
    i=0
    for contour in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if area > 1 and area < 800:
            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            cv2.rectangle(thresh,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
            center = (int(x),int(y))
            position = (center[0], center[1])
            points.append(position)

            text_color = (255,0,255)
            cv2.putText(thresh,str(i+1), position, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, text_color, 2)
            i=i+1
    pnts = np.array(points)
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(pnts)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int0(box)
    cv2.drawContours(thresh,[box],0,(0,255,0),2)
    (h, w) = img.shape[:2]
    root_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(rect[0], 0 , 1)

    rotated = cv2.warpAffine(img, root_mat,(w,h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    cv2.getRectSubPix(rotated, (w,h), center) 
    cv2.imwrite( r'rotated.jpg',rotated);
```